# Problema con javascript callback y acceso a props de react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Componente principal

```
const handleOnClose = () => {};
return (
 <TimeLapse onFinishTime={handleOnClose}/>
)
```

> TimeLapse

```
   const TimeLapse = observer(({ store, onFinishTime }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (time.limitNumber && store.user.timeLapseInQuestion === 0) {
          store.startCounterDownTime(100000, (() => {
            onFinishTime(); // llamar a mi propFunction
          }));
        }
      }, [time]);
    ...
```

> store.js

```
 const startCounterDownTime = (time, callbackFinish) => {
  callbackFinish && callbackFinish();
 }
```

en mi component `TimeLapse` cuando se ejecuta el callback de `startCounterDownTime` funciona correctamente, el problema cae cuando intenta llamar a mi propFuntion `onFinishTime` que viene en el componente principal. Me dice `TypeError: onFinishTime is not a function`

Alguien sabe el porque?

Comment: No es `const handleOnClose = () => {}` en vez de `const handleOnClose () => {}`

Comment: @FranAcuna error de dedo, pero igual no es eso.

Comment: Lo suponía. En `TimeLapse` como recibes el prop?

Comment: @DoubleM, puede que sea la config del Hook `useEffect`, y si agregas `onFinishTime` al arreglo de dependencias? es decir  [time, onFinishTime]

Comment: @g.4 tambien intente eso y no me funciono

Comment: seguro estas usando TimeLapse component en varios lugares, en uno de ellos te olvidaste pasar la funcion TimeLapse como props

Comment: @x-rw toda la razón hermano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un error comun en estos casos es que seguro estas usando TimeLapse component en varios lugares, y en uno de ellos te olvidaste pasar la funcion TimeLapse como props